# Align center depending on number of columns susy

Tags: html, css, susy, susy-sass

I am using the following style to align the columns at the center of the page using susy:

```
card{ 
@include span(3 of 12);
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But its not moving the elements (div) to center of the page by default, if I have single element it is placing it on left side and but I want that single element to be placed at the center of the page. Elements grows dynamically and they are not static.

Comment: May be this will help: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: This too: https://demos.scotch.io/visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-flexbox-playground/demos/

Answer (score 1):

The `span()` mixin generates a `float: left;` property, which keeps your item from centering. Use the function instead, to avoid unwanted output:

```
.card { 
  width: span(3 of 12);
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

**Update based on clarifying comment...**

There are two ways you might be able to center/left-align based on siblings. One uses flexbox:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card { 
  flex: 0 0 span(3 of 12);

  // add gutters to all but the first element
  & + & {
    margin-left: gutter(of 12);
  }
}
```

The other uses sibling-logic only:

```
.card { 
  @include span(3 of 12);
  outline: 1px dotted red;

  &:first-child:last-child {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

The flexbox solution keeps everything centered until you've filled up the space. The floating solution only centers when there is a single `.card`

Comment: May be my question was not clear. what i want is i want to place the elements side by side if they are more than one element else place it in the center